# Inserting current date and time to Oracle database using Java

Tags: java, oracle, datetime

I want to insert current date and time in the format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" using Java.
Which datatype is suitable for this, and which method of `PreparedStatement` do I need to use?

Comment: why not just use `sysdate` instead of passing it from Java

Comment: How to use SYSDATE with preparedstatement?

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: It’s a very broad question as it stands. Did you do any search or research prior to asking? I suspect you could have got a much more elaborate answer faster that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the datatype of the column is DATE in the database. If you want to insert the current date and time, you can either use oracle's built in `SYSDATE`:

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement('insert into your_table(date_col, ...) values (sysdate, ...)');
```

Or parameterize it and use setTimestamp() on PreparedStatement:

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement('insert into your_table (date_col, ...) values (?, ...)');
ps.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

As suggested by @Basil in the comments below, You can also use [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class:

```
ps.setObject(1 , Instant.now());
```

and while retrieving , use [`ResultSet#getObject(int/String, Class<T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-int-java.lang.Class-):

```
Instant i = rs.getObject(1, Instant.class);
```

Comment: I checked with second case. It stores value in the format "yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00".

Comment: @Nidheesh - You'd need Timestamp.. Updated my answer

Comment: I haven’t checked, but I would certainly expect a newer Oracle JDBC driver to accept an `Instant` object rather than an outdated `Timestamp`. If so, I recommend taking advantage of it.

Comment: This Answer is using troublesome  old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

> which method of PreparedStatement do I need to use

**Storing:**

```
PreparedStatement::setObject( … , java.time.Instant myInstant )
```

**Retrieving:**

```
ResultSet::getObject( … , Instant.class )
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses java.time classes. Specifically: [`PreparedStatement::setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,java.lang.Object)) and [`ResultSet::getObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject(int,java.lang.Class))

Get the current moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) by calling `Instant.now()`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , Instant.now() ) ;
```

Retrieve that value.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

Store that in a column of type akin to SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can get your expected date time format using `java.util.Date` class . If you want to store only date then you have to convert `java.util.date` to `java.sql.date`..

If you want to store all that is time and date then go for string ( i.e. varchar data type in Oracle table) ..

Comment: I recommend staying away from the long outdated `Date` classes mentioned. Better to use the modern Java date and time API, for example an `Instant`. This will also save you from converting between two different `Date` types.